# Calculate the inverse of a multi-variable function

Tags: calculus, inverse

How would I calculate the inverse of

$F(x,y)=\left( \textrm{arctan} \left(\frac{ay}{x}\right),\frac{x^2+a^2y^2}{2a}\right)$

$a$ is a constant.

Comment: The function also depends on $a$ and $p$?

Comment: edited @amcalde

Comment: By inverse you are looking for a function from the real numbers in the range of $F$ to the set of the $x$-$y$ plane that will map to that number, right?

Comment: Wait, no. I see. Your function is vector valued. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

First set $F(x,y) = (X,Y)$

Then you have 
$$ay = x \textrm{tan}X$$
and
$$x^2 + (a y )^2 = 2 a Y$$
Sub the first eqn into the second to get
$$x^2 = 2a Y /(1 + (\textrm{tan} X)^2 )$$

This should get you started.

Comment: @Mark, Do you see where to go from here?

Comment: I got $(+/- \sqrt(2ay)cos(x),+/-(\sqrt(2ay)sinx)/a)$?

Comment: That's pretty much right. I would also notice that you may have trouble when $Y$ is zero because it leads to a division by zero, but it may not really matter depending on how you look at it.

Comment: @Mark, if my answer was useful please upvote or select it.